# How to remove the Ubuntu One icon from the top bar

Tags: unity, ubuntu-one, icons

[image]

Ever since I created a Ubuntu One account, the top bar has had the little Ubuntu One cloud icon in it. I prefer not to have very many icons in the top bar, and since Ubuntu One is easy to access, I want to remove it. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the indicator to show up, you can uninstall the `indicator-sync` package, and stop the `indicator-sync-service` process from running.

Note that it is a system indicator, and other applications, such as dropbox, may use it in the future to show information about sync status, and to interact with them.

Answer (score 2):

Since Ubuntu One has stopped being developed, you can simply just remove it (and everything that has to do with it) with

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntuone-*
```

That will also remove the indicator.